# Materialize css - dynamically load tabs element

Tags: jquery, css

I am dynamically creating a set of [tabs](http://materializecss.com/tabs.html) on page load, but it is not being picked up when I run the `on` function. How can I get it working? This is my code so far:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test3">Test 3</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="test1" class="col s12">Test 1</div>
    <div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
    <div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
    <div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>    
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('body').on('load', 'ul.tabs', function() {
    $('ul.tabs').tabs()
});
```

Thanks

Comment: `ul` doesn't get `load`ed. So this function will never get triggered

Comment: Ok, I need to initialise the jQuery Plugin when the tabs are created. How would I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this jQuery Code instead, it uses AJAX to load XML Data:

```
function tabInit() {
    $('ul.tabs').tabs();
}

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    //Url to the XML-file
    url: "url/to/xml-file.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: tabInit
});
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer. But it doesn't appear to be working as the tabs are dynamically generated after the page is loaded from an xml source.

Comment: No, I am using JavaScript to pull information from the XML/XSL documents

Comment: How are you loading the XML Data?

Comment: See my updated answer, delete any code fetching the XML file and try the new code in the answer.